# Intellij / Spring Security - unable to expand - spring-security-oauth2-core dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security

When I am analyzing dependencies in intelij using `Analyze Dependencies..` feature, i am seeing that at one hierarchy i am able to expand  `spring-security-oauth2-core` and I am not able to expand the same at different hierarchy.  Why is this so.

Able to expand below -
[image]

Unable to expand below -
[image]

Seems quite trivial, but if I am looking at a new dependency I would not be able to determine for sure if it's an end-node (i.e has no further deps) until I can find an answer for this Q.

Edit - Below is the pom.xml if some one want to try at there end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-only</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security-only</name>
    <description>spring-security-only</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not show the nested dependencies for the **omitted** dependencies.

Comment: could you elaborate your answer. +1.  1) Do you means it's a limitation from intellij. Or it will be same even if analyzed in eclipse or  with `mvn dependency:tree`. 2) how do i  determine if it's an omitted deps. Just infer based on the situation or intellij can show that.